# Dragging a Panel Leaves Behind "Ghost" Copies of it

Tags: c#

I'm dragging a panel by using the following code

```
public void researchMenu_MouseisDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            dragging = true;
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;
        }

    }

    public void researchMenu_MouseisUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dragging = false;

    }

    public void researchMenu_MouseMoves(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dragging)
        {
            this.researchMenu.Location = new Point(e.X + this.researchMenu.Left - x, e.Y + this.researchMenu.Top - y);
        }


    }
```

and it leaves behind a "ghost" copy of itself, like when an application would crash in Windows XP.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAmVL.png) is an example of what it's doing.

I am honestly at a loss as to how to fix it, I figured that it might be the group boxes being transparent, but I changed them to be an opaque color and the "ghost" was still left.

Comment: What are you using? winforms? wpf?

Comment: Have you changed the event names to confuse us or the system ;-) - I can't confirm you problem, here this works fine. What else is in the Paint event etc..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more detail on how you're drawing/animating, it looks like the parent isn't getting updated during the drag. Try adding some sort of redraw or paint call for the parent during the researchMenu_MouseMoves event.